# Error JS in a feature writing html in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I have a little error when I execute this function in IE11:

```
function clearText(someText){
    return someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
}
$.getJSON('/getElements/', callback)
            .done(function(fragments){
                $.each(fragments, function(propertyName,value){
                    if (clearText(value.trim())!==""){
                        $("."+propertyName).empty().append(clearText(value));
                        //$("."+propertyName).html(clearText(value));
                        //document.getElementsByClassName(propertyName)[0].innerHTML = clearText(value);
                    }
                });
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            });
```

In all others browsers, there's no problem, empty().append() works. But IE11 don't accept empty.append, or .html, or .innerHTML
I have yet many data in my array "fragments".

Someone can see where is the problem ?

Thanks.

K.

Comment: What exactly the error you're getting?

Comment: IE11 don't write any HTML in: $("."+propertyName).empty().append(clearText(value));

Comment: Can we see your html ? :) IE is more sensitive about html errors than Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Do you see any error message in console? If not, your question title is misleading

Comment: When I use console, I have no soucy.
If I use alert(), I can see all datas

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I think I solve the problem.
When I use .getJson, IE use a cache (default cache for getJson is true), but FF and other don't use this cache.